# Pantheon's Ult Destination Visible In Bushes?

Tags: league-of-legends

I know that Nunu's ult area is invisible if he casts it in a bush and the enemies are outside the bush, but I was wondering if Panth's is ult visible to enemies outside the bush if he is landing in the bush.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, Pantheon's ult is still visible. The logic here is that Nunu's ult is centered on himself. Thus, if you walk into the bush during a mistimed Nunu ult, you could get lucky and interrupt him. On the other hand, Pantheon's ult is targeted somewhere else on the map. His intended target usually has no way of interrupting him, so hiding the AoE marker would be unfair.

Comment: I think that besides interruption another factor is that panth's ult is a global teleport. All global teleports are visible in lol for obvious reasons.

Comment: @bolov Reksai has a global teleport that is not visible... (?)

Comment: @Pierre Reksai's global teleport requires her to target one of her tunnel entrances, which are visible to enemy champions at all times and can be removed by standing on them for 1.5 seconds. Also, the target entrance will glow while the ultimate is being channeled and all players (enemy and allied) receive a global audio cue.

Comment: This isn't exactly true. I'm not sure if this is a bug but pantheon's ult indicator CAN disappear if his centerpoint is directly on a bush. See [this video](https://youtu.be/MW3kJ9x6VNc?t=29s). Now you can very clearly see Shiphtur standing outside the top lane tri-bush with no pantheon in sight at 0:29 but at 0:30 you see him take a chunk of his HP as damage right as he's about to enter the bush and as he actually enters at 0:31 you can see the end of Pantheon's ult animation and the big ring it normally makes.