# Why does nunu stay hidden after he completes channeling and deals damage with his ultimate/

Tags: league-of-legends

I know the question title seems subjective, however the reasoning behind that is because its not an easy question for me to phrase right now. The example I will use is Sion, Lux, and Nami.

These champions have knock up, slow and knock up skill shot abilities that cc the target and deal damage.
Now if I were in the brush and cast these skills, after the target is damaged they gain vision of me if I am within range, right!? so in Lux's case she would q e then kill you with ult, crowd controlling you with q so that you do not react to her e. In Nami's case she would q and then and with the help of the adc chunk you. You see her and Lux where the damage is applied. I am not 100% certain about Nami as this is something I just recently thought of and I have not had to deal with a Nami in that scenario recently to make any comments about it. So I watched a stream where sneaky was q knocked up by Sion followed by an e that did not reveal Sion's location through out the entire exchange.

If you watch it you will notice that after he landed he was momentary stunned and though he issued a move command. His champion did not move until after the stun duration. During the stun duration he is hit with an e you see the ability exit the brush but Sion's location is not given before and after the e reaches sneaky's Twitch.

Which leads me to believe that Crowd control can affect a champions vision. Taking that statement to consideration why is Nunu's location not given while he slows a team with his ultimate and after he deals damage. His ultimate is a slow so why is it he stays hidden?

Comment: A specific time frame would be helpful.

Comment: Its because its an AOE not targeted. AOE/skillshots dont reveal the person that casts them

Comment: Skills of any type don't reveal you in brush AFAIK, only auto attacks.

Comment: I had it set to 15:50

Comment: that is interesting because when i played sion on his release and had e then charged q they dodged it even though i was in the brush and my teammates were like i shouldn't have charged like that because they can see me

Comment: This question is sort of related to yours: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/201200/pantheons-ult-destination-visible-in-bushes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was simple:

Nunu's ultimate is AOE (Area of Effect), Hes channeling his ult' while hiding in the bush **does not** reveal his location to an enemy.
Why?

The reason: He is launching a skill which is ***directly connected to his champion model***.
The slow effect of his ultimate when you walk into his ultimate's range while he is channeling will also **not** be visible to you.

About the video: **Sion** is channeling his Q while hiding in the bush which also doesn't reveal him since his Q is connected to his champion model.

You only see the champion and their channeling skill if you have vision of that bush.

Lux's skills are projectiles. You might know where Lux is when you see the projectile flying towards which direction, but you can't get to know Lux's location directly.

Only auto attacks against an enemy unit will directly reveal a champion who is standing in a bush.